# Vague compactness of a particular set of measures

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

On $\mathbb{R}$ consider the sequence of compact sets $K_n = [-n,n]$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and set $H := \bigcap_n \{ \mu \in M(\mathbb{R}) \mid |\mu(K_n)| \leq 1 \}$, where $M(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of finite signed measures on $\mathbb{R}$. Is it true that $\sup_{\mu \in H} |\mu(K)| < \infty$ for any compact set $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ or that $\sup_{\mu \in H} |\int f \, d\mu| < \infty$ for all continuous functions $f$ with compact support? If not, is it possible to choose the compact exhaustion $K_n$ of $\mathbb{R}$ in such a way that the above property holds? (This would prove that $H$ is a vaguely compact subset of $M(\mathbb{R})$.)

Note that this property is satisfied if we only consider positive measures $\mu \geq 0$, since then $K \subseteq K_n$ for some $n$ and $\mu(K) \leq \mu (K_n) \leq 1$. However, in my application I need to consider signed measures $\mu$.

EDIT: For the first question I think to have found a counterexample:
Consider the compact set $K := \{ \frac{1}{k} \mid k \geq 1 \} \cup \{ 0 \}$. Set $\mu_k := \sum_{j=1}^k ( \delta_{\frac{1}{j}} - \delta_{-\frac{1}{j}})$ for $k \geq 1$. Then $\mu_k \in H$ for all $k$ since $\mu_k[-1,1] = 0$ and therefore $\mu_k(K_n) = 0$ for all $n$. But $\mu_k(K) = k$ and this implies $\sup_{\mu \in H} |\mu(K)| = \infty$. In particular, the set $H$ is not vaguely compact. In this regard, I assume that one can construct a similar counterexample for any compact exhaustion $K_n$. The compactness result for positive measures does not extend to signed measures.